# Complex Fourier series of $\sin(x)$, [$0,\pi$)

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve the following question:

[image]

I have tried to make an attempt at this question but I am not sure where to begin.
My current understanding is to apply $f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(x)e^{-inx} dx$ to find the $c_n$ coefficient for the general formula of a complex Fourier series $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}$.

Is this the correct approach to this question?

Any help, clarification or suggestions will be **greatly** appreciated so I begin to solve this question. Thank you!

EDIT: attempted to evaluate $\int sin(x)e^{-ix} dx$, as a start (dont worry i did not forget about $e^{-inx}$ to obtain $\frac{-ix}{2} - \frac{1}{4} e^{-2ix} + c$ but still not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} dx$$

$$=  \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) e^{-inx} dx$$

Now writing $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} -e^{-ix}}{2i}$, we can obtain $\hat{f}(n)$.

Once we have that we can write the Fourier series as:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n) e^{inx}$$

Comment: so i have to evaluate $ \frac{1}{2 \Pi} \int_{0}^{\Pi} \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} e^{-inx} dx$ ?

Comment: i obtained $\frac{-ix}{2} - \frac{1}{4} e^{-2ix} + c$ is this correct?

Comment: @lohboys I found $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\dfrac{e^{-in\pi}+1}{1-n^2}$

Comment: Yes that integration will give you the Fourier Series.

Comment: @Nosrati i've tried to work that integration again but don't seem to obtain your answer. Could you show me how you obtained your answer?

Comment: @lohboys $$
c_n
=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}e^{-inx}dx
=\dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\left(\dfrac{e^{ix(1-n)}}{i(1-n)}-\dfrac{e^{ix(-1-n)}}{i(-1-n)}\right)_0^\pi
=\dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\left(\dfrac{e^{i\pi(1-n)}-1}{i(1-n)}+\dfrac{e^{-i\pi(1+n)}-1}{i(1+n)}\right)_0^\pi
=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\dfrac{e^{-in\pi}+1}{1-n^2}
$$

Comment: @Nosrati thank you!

Comment: @Nosrati may I ask how you went from the 2nd to the 3rd step (integrating) and then from the third to fourth step? Im stuck with the integrating in the 2nd step

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solutions is using fourier relations as f.g -> F * G muliplication goes to convolution. Your function is sin multiplied by a top hat function convolved by a comb. The transform will thus be the two deltas from the sin function convolved by a sinc times by a comb (with a phase shift to compensate for the offset of the comb).